# Array of objects show objects with specified key first

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting

I'm trying to sort an array of objects and integrating it into a filtering system. I don't want to remove the objects I'm not interested in, just move them to the bottom.

So far I've grouped my objects, like this

```
const arrayOfObjects = [{type: 'type1', title: 'Object 1'}, {type: 'type2', title: 'Object 2'}, {type: 'type1', title: 'Object 3'}]
```

Into

```
const groupedArrayOfObjects = [{type: 'type1', objects: [{type: 'type1', title: 'Object 1'}, ...type1, 
                              {type: 'type2', objects: [{type: 'type2', title: 'Object 2'}, ...type2]
```

I want to sort this so say `type2` has index `0` and the rest of the objects are displayed after that. I've been able to sort it alphabetically but not based on string value.

`groupedArrayOfObjects.filter(obj => (obj.type === 'type1'))` would filter out the objects I'm not interested in. This would work if I knew how to put them back in only with a index thats not 0. Help me please.

edit: to clarify, I wish for something like a function that orders my objects after a key, like showing the objects with `type1` first and then showing all the others after that. Something like a priority.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.sort()`, and pass in a paramater for the `sortKey`

```js
const arrayOfObjects = [
  {type: 'type1', title: 'Object 1'},
  {type: 'type2', title: 'Object 2'},
  {type: 'type1', title: 'Object 3'}
]

function orderByKey (arr, sortKey) {
  let tempArr = [...arr];
  
  return tempArr.sort(({type}) => type == sortKey ? -1 : 1);
};

let a = orderByKey(arrayOfObjects, 'type1');
let b = orderByKey(arrayOfObjects, 'type2');

console.log(a);
console.log(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Array.prototype.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) with a custom compare function based on `type`.

```
groupedArrayOfObjects.sort((a, b) => b.type === 'type1' ? 1 : -1)
```

So if group `b` is listed behind group `a`, but has the wanted type, we give `b` the precedence.

I hope this helps you?

Answer (score 0):

For group you can try this(it's more readable):

```
const groupedObjects = {};
for ( let obj of arrayOfObjects ) {
  if(!groupedObjects[obj.type]) groupedObjects[obj.type] = [];
  groupedObjects[obj.type].push(obj);
}
```

now you got `groupedObjects` like a

```
{
  type1: [
    {type: 'type1', title: 'Object1'},
    {type: 'type1', title: 'Object3'},
  ],
  type2: [
    {type: 'type2', title: 'Object2'}
  ]
}
```

Or you can use `groupBy` from package `lodash`

For sorting use `sort()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort
If you want sort by `type`:

```
arrayOfObjects.sort((a,b) => {
  if (a.type > b.type) return 1;
  else if (a.type < b.type) return -1;
  return 0;
})
```